# en Eclipse ctrl+flecha derecha a veces no funciona

Tags: eclipse, ide

Estoy acostumbrado a usar las teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> para desplazarme a la siguiente palabra y <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> para seleccionar la siguiente palabra. Pero me pasa a veces que en eclipse no funciona.

En las preferencias *Window->Preferences->General->keys* la combinación aparece correctamente, pero a pesar de ello, no pasa nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La ventana de inicio causa este tipo de error en el editor aparentemente lleva años sin corregirse (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426557).

A veces al iniciar el editor cuando se tienen muchos plugins, o en alguna versión más pesada como sts se observa que no se puede usar esa combinación de control y flechas para desplazarse en la ventana del editor, pero que en otras ventanas como la consola funciona apropiadamente.

Una solución rápida es **deshabilitar que aparezca al pantalla de bienvenida** o puedes también **reiniciar** eclipse para que los métodos corran más eficientemente gracias al *warmup de Java*.

Comment: Podrias aceptar tu propia respuesta?

Comment: @gbianchi como tiene votos negativos tal vez lo más conveniente para mí sea aliminarla :C

Comment: Ahora esta en 0.. Igual a alguien mas le paso porque puso otra respuesta

Answer (score 0):

por mi parte no me servia cuando precionas "ctrl + space" para autocompletar los comandos como sysout (para poner un print), lo que hice fue cambiarlo "Window/General/keys", te desplazas hasta abajo donde esta Content Assist y allí cambie el Binding a "Alt + ." y otra cosa que el cambie fue en donde dice "When" a "Editing Text" y listo